# Is there a way to indicate a function will only be called by init?

Tags: kotlin

I am thinking of initializing some value, instead of complicating in the `init` function, I refactor into a function e.g. `callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit()`, and have my `finalValue` initialize there.

```
val finalValue: String

init {
    callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit()
}

fun callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit() {
    finalValue = "Something"
}
```

Clearly it will complaint `val cannot be reassigned`. I clearly know that the `callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit()` will only be called in the `init`. But is there a way for me to let the Compiler know this, so it doesn't complaint?

Note:

I know I can do something as below

```
val finalValue: String

init {
    finalValue = callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit()
}

fun callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit() : String {
    return "Something"
}
```

But I just want to explore if there's a way to refactor `init` better and could place the initialization in some function instead of have to do it in `init`.

Answer (score 7):

In kotlin you can declare functions in almost any scope. For example, you can declare function inside init block and it will only available within that block:

```
class Example { 
    val finalValue: String

    init {
        fun callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit(): String {
            return "Something"
        }

        finalValue = callSomeFunctionThatWillOnlyBeCalledByInit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SimY4's answer works perfectly fine, but there is another way. So, this is an addition.

You don't need to do the initialization in `init` at all to achieve what you want:

```
class Example {

    val finalValue: String = {
        // do something complex 
        "test"
    }()
}
```

The lambda can only be run once during initialization of the class. There is no way to invoke it afterwards.

Comment: I may be wrong but I would imagine that the reason why you want a function might be that you want to use recursive calls. Although your code also works, with a named function you can declare it as `tailrec fun` an get all the benefits of tail recursive functions.

Comment: @SimY4 no, I was not after recursion. I was just looking for another way. I think, the multiple options where confusing. I reduced it to the lambda one. Thx

Answer (score -1):

There's no separate construct in the language to support this, your properties have to be initialized either inline with their declaration, or inside the initializer blocks.

If you want your initialization to have separated sections, you can:

- Join your declarations and assignments, if your initializations are simple enough, and organize the properties into groups:

  ```
  // Strings
  val myString = "foo"

  // Ints
  val myInt = 256
  ```
- Use an initializer  block and just comments for sections:

  ```
  val myString: String
  val myInt: Int

  init {
      // Strings
      myString = "foo"

      // Ints
      myInt = 256
  }
  ```
- Use multiple initializer  blocks, [these will be executed in order from top to bottom](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). Having a separate function that sets a `val` to a value would be problematic because you could possibly call it at a later time again, after initialization. If you use initializer blocks instead, you can be sure that these will only be invoked once.

  ```
  val myString: String
  val myInt: Int

  init {
      myString = "foo"
  }

  init {
      myInt = 256
  }
  ```